# How to increase the space between participants in a ZenUML sequence diagram?

Tags: sequence-diagram

I have been using [ZenUML](https://app.zenuml.com/) website for generating sequence diagrams in my project. It's really handy. However, sometimes I want to increase the spaces between participants if there're many to make it better for presentation. I wonder how can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to implement this depending on what effect you want to achieve:

If you want increase the space between all objects use the following CSS:

```css
#diagram .lifeline {
    margin: 0 40px; /* default is 0 2pxp */
}
```

OR, if you want to increase the width(margin) of one participant:

```css
#diagram #YOUR_PARTICIPANT.lifeline {
  margin: 0 80px;
}
```

The effect of the second one looks like:
[image]